# Is it possible to use intellij idea and eclipse together

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

for someone it may seems a little weird but still I want to know if it's possible or not. We have a lot of projects which coded on eclipse so far and some of us wants to jump into intellij idea world.

1. Can we be able to run the projects via eclipse and intellij together at the same time? I mean for instance I'll be using intellij idea while another friend of mine will be using eclipse instead of intellij idea on the same projects, is it possible?
2. If it's possible, would it create any problem for version control systems such as subversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subversion will have no problem at all, but I recommend you in that case that you rely your java build configuration (sources, compiler level, dependencies, etc.) on maven or gradle instead of doing it twice, once for every IDE you are using.  Then both maven or gradle should be able to generate IDE-specific configuration files for each environment and you would work in the same conditions.

Actually I like the idea of working with a managed and automated build process, so if anyone is brave and bold enough to use vim... they can use it without problems, and still build their app.

Comment: This is indeed the way to go. Our project folders (in SVN repository) only consists of a src directory and a pom.xml file. Nothing else! That way, each developer can - and must - configure his IDE as he wishes. (In Eclipse, this is a simple right-click, Configure ..., Convert to Maven project.)

Answer (score 4):

> Can we be able to run the projects via eclipse and intellij together at the same time?

Yes, because these IDE store their project data and configuration in different files, so they don't step on each other:

- Eclipse stores its files in `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings`
- IntelliJ stores its files in `.idea`, `*.iml`

> If it's possible, would it create any problem for version control systems such as subversion?

Not at all.

Btw I do this too sometimes: I have projects where members use different IDE: IntelliJ, Android Studio, Eclipse, with no problems.