# How to get Eclipse and IntelliJ working together in an existing project of IntelliJ (optional with changes in source directly transferred)

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

in another question
([Is it possible to use intellij idea and eclipse together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160987/is-it-possible-to-use-intellij-idea-and-eclipse-together/21161075))
is written: Eclipse and IntelliJ can work together, because they store their project data and configuration in different files: Eclipse stores its files in .project, .classpath, .settings - IntelliJ stores its files in .idea, *.iml

and as a comment: I have projects where members use different IDE: IntelliJ, Android Studio, Eclipse, with no problems.

I would like to know more precise how to do this?
I have a project from my company which is already running on spring boot and with a pom.xml in the folder "develop" and we are "forced" to take IntelliJ by preinstalled Notebook and I prefer to work on Eclipse.
I made a fresh installation of eclipse on this notebook to bring it together the described present project.

I understood to use the: IntelliJ -> File -> Export -> Project to Eclipse in a first step. Actual I took a seperate workspace for eclipse in a folder which I called: "develop.Eclipse" But thats the first hindrance, is this the right way? And I would like/try not to use this CodeTogether which they start to push now everywhere...
Can someone tell me how to go on? (more detailed more better ;-) )(W10/Java11/IntelliJUlt2021/Eclipse2021.3)

Best regards

Schubi

Answer (score 3):

Maven is THE project definition and build system on your project, particular IDE is secondary concern in this setup.

I don't see why you should export anything from IDEA to work with Eclipse. Just import Maven project into the Eclipse, add Eclipse specific files into your version control system ignore file (.gitignore for Git) as needed, and enjoy your IDE.